# apache2 how to host multiple ssl in single server

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, ssl-certificate, apache2

I'm trying to get 2 ssl server on one apache server,

on is the main site and the other is the subdomain,

Here are the .conf files:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

     SSLProxyEngine On
     ProxyPreserveHost On
     ServerName site.com

     SSLEngine on
     SSLCertificateFile /FOLDER/site.crt
     SSLCertificateKeyFile /FOLDER/site.key
     SSLCACertificateFile /FOLDER/site.ca-bundle


     Timeout 2400
     ProxyTimeout 2400
     ProxyBadHeader Ignore


     SetEnv proxy-initial-not-pooled
     SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1

     ProxyPass / http://10.0.0.101:8888/  retry=1 acquire=3000 timeout=600 Keepalive=On
     ProxyPassReverse / http://10.0.0.101:8888/

</VirtualHost>



<VirtualHost *:443>

     SSLProxyEngine On
     ProxyPreserveHost On
     ServerName sub.site.com

     SSLEngine on
     SSLCertificateFile /FOLDER/sub_Site.crt
     SSLCertificateKeyFile /FOLDER/sub_Site.key
     SSLCACertificateFile /FOLDER/sub_site.ca-bundle


     Timeout 2400
     ProxyTimeout 2400
     ProxyBadHeader Ignore


     SetEnv proxy-initial-not-pooled
     SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1

     ProxyPass / http://10.0.0.100:8888/  retry=1 acquire=3000 timeout=600 Keepalive=On
     ProxyPassReverse / http://10.0.0.100:8888/

</VirtualHost>
```

for some reason, the main ssl ends up picking the ssl certificate from the  sub domain,

can anyone see where I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it makes a difference, but maybe move the ServerName entries to the top of each VirtualHost section.

Another option you might explore, if it fits your business need, would be to use an SSL certificate with Subject Alternative Names for each FQDN (sometimes referred to as a "Multi-Domain" certificate).  The Apache wiki has [more information](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/UnderstandingMultiUseSSLCertificates) on SAN and wildcard certificates.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Apache are you using? This configuration looks just fine and like what I use with Apache 2.4. In order for this to work, the client must support SNI, which all current versions of modern browsers do.